# android app crashes on starting an activity from fragment on 2.3

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to start an Activity from a Fragment Class like below.

```
List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ItemDetail Item = DetailItem.get(position - 1);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        ComplateDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("KEY", Item);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT :**

ItemDetail Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ItemDetail implements Serializable {

    public float ispoints;
    public String fullDescription;

    public ItemDetail() {

    }
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public ItemDetail(ItemsDetail item , float rating , float ispoints)
    {

        this.ImageUrl = item.ImageUrl;
        this.Name = item.Name;
        this.UrlKey = item.UrlKey;
        this.DateCreated = item.DateCreated;
        try{ this.dateCreated = this.dateFormat.parse(item.DateCreated); } catch (Exception e){}
        this.rating = rating;
        this.ispoints = ispoints;
    }

}
```

Its working fine on devices above 3.0 but crashes on 2.3.6. Please tell me whats I am doing wrong here I have also tried `getActivity.startActivity(intent);`.
Below is the logcat complete output

```
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no char field 'exponential'
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.EmulatedFields.put(EmulatedFields.java:459)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.EmulatedFieldsForDumping.put(EmulatedFieldsForDumping.java:83)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.writeObject(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:591)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1062)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1008)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.text.DecimalFormat.writeObject(DecimalFormat.java:1215)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1205)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1205)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1171)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1130)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5767)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1384)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2988)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:833)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:856)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at com.codenterprise.left.fragment.shops.ShopsTopFragment$2.onItemClick(ShopsTopFragment.java:121)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3569)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:10:38.158: E/AndroidRuntime(21412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Metho
```

**EDITE 2 :**

This is ItemsDetail Class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ItemsDetail implements Serializable {

    public String Name;
    public String ImageUrl;
    public String DateCreated;
    public Date dateCreated;
    public DateFormat dateFormat;

    public ItemsDetail() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

    public ItemsDetail(String title, String detail) {
        this.Name = title;
        this.Detail = detail;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post implementation of `ItemDetail` class.

Comment: @erakitin its a POJO class that implements Serializable.

Comment: @erakitin now see the above code I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with `DecimalFormatSymbols` serialization in Android 2.3. You can see the description [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14495). If you want a workaround, remove fields that use `DecimalFormatSymbols` (such as `SimpleDateFormat` etc).

**UPD:**

1. I don't sure but try to declare `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat` field as `static final`.
2. Or you can remove `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat` field and use local variable instead of this field inside constructor:

.

```
public ItemDetail(ItemsDetail item , float rating , float ispoints) {
    this.ImageUrl = item.ImageUrl;
    this.Name = item.Name;
    this.UrlKey = item.UrlKey;
    this.DateCreated = item.DateCreated;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // change to your format
    try {
        this.dateCreated = format.parse(item.DateCreated);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.rating = rating;
    this.ispoints = ispoints;
}
```

Comment: So whats the alternative for it if I have to Parse a date ?

Comment: Did you remove `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat` field?

Comment: Yes I have removed that and replaced with the local one as you said `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: What kind of types are other fields? Please post full code of `ItemDetail` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58691/discussion-between-erakitin-and-user3294034).

Answer (score 0):

This is Android bug, see this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14495